# Remove unwanted portion from a signal in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter, scipy, signal-processing

I have a signal which measures current and save it the form of 1D array. 
The signal follows a typical patters and I will be doing some research work on that pattern.

But before the pattern appears, there lies some noise or unwanted signal.  I want to filter or neglect that unwanted portion from my signal.

`Refer picture below` for better understanding

Also given some [sample data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oxco5MV_fS6F17Uf4_t8qVCjtnR8Td8L) to play with. (2 columns included - index & current values )

I tried with many approaches like `sliding_window/finding_peaks` from scipy. but nothing turns out.

Thanks

Comment: Will you need to automatically apply this to future data as well?

Comment: @kynnem Yes, approx 30 signals are like this (with different Noise levels), so I need it for the future as well.

Comment: What are your criteria for distinguishing signal from noise? Length of signal? Threshold?

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify what is unique in that part of the signal in all your samples.

Do you want to remove

- 10 seconds
- the second valley below a certain value
- two little valleys below a certain threshold

Or if the part you want to remove looks exactly or is very simliar all the time you can use [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) to find out where that part is. You can use the [scipy.signal.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) to calculate it.